# User Authentication with Mobile Number and OTP in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

How to allow user, to login our Laravel application using Mobile Number and OTP

Comment: Maybe this package is your answer.....  https://github.com/j42/laravel-twilio
Check it out https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-implement-sms-verification-or-otp-in-l52?page=1

Answer (score 9):

I had implemented it through following approach,
On Laravel 5.7 and Passport:

**File Path:** /app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php

**Edit:**

```
$credentials = request(['mobile_no', 'password', 'email', 'otp']);
```

**File Path:** /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php

**Edit:**

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    if (isset($credentials['password'])) {
      $plain = $credentials['password'];
      return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
    }else{
      $otp = $credentials['otp'];
      if ($otp==$user->getAuthOtp()) {
        return true;
      }
    }
}
```

**File Path:** /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Authenticatable.php

**Add:**

```
public function getAuthOtp()
    {
        return $this->otp;
    }
```

**Note:** Using this user is also able to login with OTP and password, I will update my answer when I found an appropriate solution for that.

Comment: Thank you so much...This solution also worked in laravel 6. if someone want using bcrypt, just add `Str::contains($key, 'your_key')` into the if condition of `retrieveByCredentials` method.now you can access to your_key in `validateCredentials`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use any package. I think you will be confused by using this. See this ( https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-55-login-with-only-mobile-number-using-laravel-custom-auth) tutorial and make custom based login with mobile and varify OTP as well.

Comment: Where is concept of otp ?